# service fabric local cluster setup error

Tags: visual-studio, azure-service-fabric

Following link below to set-up and run local cluster.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-create-your-first-application-in-visual-studio

Currently when running the application, it errors out setting up local cluster.

Dev environment:
Windows 10,
Visual Studio 2017 trial,
Docker for Windows (Although not used)

PowerShell script execution has been enabled and visual studio was run as administrator.

Error message: The PowerShell script failed to execute. See the Output window for details.

Output Window:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyApplication, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>------ Deploy started: Project: MyApplication, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>Started executing script 'GetApplicationExistence'.
2>Finished executing script 'GetApplicationExistence'.
2>Time elapsed: 00:00:02.1304224
2>Started executing script 'Set-LocalClusterReady'.
2>powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\DefaultLocalClusterSetup.psm1'; Set-LocalClusterReady -createOneNodeCluster $true"
2>--------------------------------------------
2>Local Service Fabric Cluster is not setup...
2>Please wait while we setup the Local Service Fabric Cluster. This may take few minutes...
2>Stop-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'FabricHostSvc'.
2>At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1:144 char:5
2>+ Stop-Service FabricHostSvc -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
2>+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2> + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (FabricHostSvc:String) [Stop-Service], ServiceCommandException
2> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopServiceCommand
2>
2>WARNING: System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Remove-ServiceFabricNodeConfiguration' is not
2> recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
2>a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
2>
2> at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception
2>exception)
2>
2> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2>
2> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2>
2> at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2>WARNING: Remove-ServiceFabricNodeConfiguration throws exceptions
2>
2>Using Cluster Data Root: C:\SfDevCluster\Data
2>Using Cluster Log Root: C:\SfDevCluster\Log
2>
2>The generated json path is C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5D74.tmp.json
2>Processing and validating cluster config.
2>Failed to open base key for machine ComputerFullName to check if machine is IOT Core.
2>Test-ServiceFabricClusterManifest : The term 'Test-ServiceFabricClusterManifest' is not recognized as the name of a
2>cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
2>that the path is correct and try again.
2>At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1:504 char:5
2>+ Test-ServiceFabricClusterManifest -ClusterManifestPath "$manifest ...
2>+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2> + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Test-ServiceFabricClusterManifest:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
2> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
2>
2>PrepareClusterManifest : Could not validate cluster manifest
2>'C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\LAP000338-Server-ScaleMin.xml'
2>At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1:530 char:21
2>+ ... ifestFile = PrepareClusterManifest $manifestFileTemplate $imageStoreC ...
2>+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2> + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
2> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,PrepareClusterManifest
2>
2>ScriptHalted
2>At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1:508 char:9
2>+ throw
2>+ ~~~~~
2> + CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: (:) [], RuntimeException
2> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptHalted
2>
2>Finished executing script 'Set-LocalClusterReady'.
2>Time elapsed: 00:00:10.9335415
2>The PowerShell script failed to execute.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Have you restart the machine after the setup?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.. yes restarted computer, reinstalled SDK, repeated enable powershell execution, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To get to the point first, it was the installer issue.
When I was installing the Service Fabric SDK, something happened during the installation, let's say network error or installation was not complete however I somehow missed it, human error.

I am not sure how I missed it but the point is, I tried to uninstall and reinstall the SDK a few times just in case to make sure SDK was installed completely.  And the problem was, the initial incorrect installation done was lingering throughout this whole process because there were directories and files not completely removed by uninstallation, such as registry keys.

After I manually delete registry keys and directories and reinstalled the SDK and now everything seems fine.

To help anyone having similar issue, edited instruction below.
Original article of the instruction in (https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/566)

```
1. Uninstall Microsoft Service Fabric SDK.
2. Uninstall Service Fabric tools using the Visual Studio Installer.
3. Delete folder: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric
4. Delete folder from registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Service Fabric
5. Reboot PC
6. Download Microsoft Web PI (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started) install the Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK. Btw. after I've deleted registry entries of SF, I've noticed that Web PI has finally installed three needed components (not only Azure Service Fabric SDK as it was for previous re-installations):
  Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)
  Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162
  Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK - 3.2.162

7. Install Service Fabric tools using the Visual Studio Installer.
8. Create test project in Visual Studio 2017 and run it. Visual Studio created cluster automatically.
```

P.S. After following the steps and if you still can't install Azure Service Fabric Runtime, it could be remaining in "Add or Remove Programs" list, then delete registry key manually: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ServiceFabric  (or is it "Service Fabric" with space..?)

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day! I had the same issue: installing some of the prerequisites failed. And just simply reinstalling the Microsoft Service Fabric did not help, but completely removing it (from registry as well) did the trick.

Comment: Wasted 2 hours on this. Don`t know how much would wast without your answer. Thanks man :))

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Microsoft Service Fabric SDK and Service Fabric from Windows add/remove option.

Uninstall Service Fabric tools using the Visual Studio Installer (using the modify option to uncleck and apply updates). This will ensure Visual Studio generated files are removed.

Delete Service Fabric folder manually under: C:\Program Files
Folder name might be the SF or Microsoft Service Fabric or Service Fabric or another name depending on previous setup.

Delete folder from registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Service Fabric

Reboot PC

Download Service Fabric, SDK and Service Fabric Runtime. Download sources -

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=839354

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server

Open PowerShell as admin.

run “Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope CurrentUser”

Then

run “.\CreateServiceFabricCluster.ps1 -ClusterConfigFilePath .\ClusterConfig.Unsecure.DevCluster.json -AcceptEULA“

Install Service Fabric SDK

Install Service Fabric tools using the Visual Studio Installer (using modify option, check Service Fabric option and apply updates).

Rebuild solution. Make sure your C drive has enough free spaces and manifest file has corrected domain\username, password to publish.