# service fabric local cluster setup error - CommandNotFoundException

Tags: .net, azure-service-fabric

Test-ServiceFabricClusterManifest : The term 'Test-ServiceFabricClusterManifest' is not recognized as the name of a
3>cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
3>that the path is correct and try again.
3>At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1:804 char:5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [service fabric local cluster setup error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52012157/service-fabric-local-cluster-setup-error)

Comment: No. I follow all the steps but still facing same issue.