# Cannot setup Service Fabric Local Cluster manager

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to install and run Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager. When I try to "Setup Local Cluster", I get the following error:

> > TerminatingError(): "Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified.""

This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified.

Detailed error log:

---

Windows PowerShell transcript start

Start time: 20230130230050

Username:

RunAs User:

Configuration Name:

Machine:

Host Application: PowerShell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\DevClusterSetup.ps1' -Auto -PathToClusterLogRoot C:\SFDevCluster\Log -SetupLogFileName DevClusterSetup.log -CreateOneNodeCluster

Process ID: 7912

PSVersion: 5.1.22621.963

PSEdition: Desktop

PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.22621.963

BuildVersion: 10.0.22621.963

CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000

WSManStackVersion: 3.0

PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3

SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1

---

Transcript started, output file is C:\SFDevCluster\Log\DevClusterSetup.log

PS>TerminatingError(): "Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified.""

> > TerminatingError(): "Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified.""

> > TerminatingError(): "Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified.""

This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified.

---

Windows PowerShell transcript end

End time: 20230130230052

Service Fabric version: 9.1.1436.9590

Service Fabric SDK version: 6.1.1436.9590

Can someone help me in resolving this? I have tried uninstalling (with deleting the registry) and installing it. The issue still persists.

P.S. I have executed the steps mentioned in [service fabric local cluster setup error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52012157/service-fabric-local-cluster-setup-error). But didn't help.

Service Fabric local cluster should be running with nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue, and following the guideline from [Access control list not in canonical form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70173642/access-control-list-not-in-canonical-form) fixed the issue for me. Specifically, see if this returns any failures:

`icacls.exe C:\FDevCluster /verify /T /C /L /Q`

If you see output that looks like this:

```
SFDevCluster: Ace entries not in canonical order.
SFDevCluster\Data: Ace entries not in canonical order.
SFDevCluster\Log: Ace entries not in canonical order.
SFDevCluster\Data\ImageStoreShare: Ace entries not in canonical order.
```

then run this command to fix it and reset the ACLs to a correct format:

`icacls.exe SFDevCluster /reset /T /C /L /Q`